# Change hover state jQuery without using hover function?

Tags: jquery, css, events, hover

I have assigned a hover state to certain element using css. After a particular event I want to change that hover state using jQuery. I want to change :hover class selector that i have mentioned in css file. I knwo i can implement using `.hover` function but I don't want to use that because this is not suitable with my application. In my application this change in hover state is for certain time that means after that certain time I have to unbind the hover event. But in my app there are many conditional module where i need to call this unbind event. Many inefficient calls to unbind what I don't want.

```
elem {
  width:10px;
}
elem:hover {
  width:20px;
}
```

I want to change width of the `hover` state from say `20px to 40px`. I want to use something simple like `.css('width','100px')` but how to call this function on `:hover` selector.

Comment: Can you not just change the `elem:hover` rule in the CSS? I don't think that `hover()` would be less efficient than any other method you apply.

Comment: Why you a not using `CSS` for this goal?

Comment: @David, I am not saying that `hover()` is inefficient in direct sense. Actually in my app I have to do the same thing with `hover,focus,active`. So instead of calling bind and unbind many times is there any way to simplify this in one or two step. May be something like adding or removing `class`

Comment: @Vladimir, I have change that dynamically, say on the basis of current width available on the page.

Comment: @knoxxs  width can be set relatively to parent div (say in %), or with [mediaqueries](http://mediaqueri.es/)

Comment: @Vladmir, Actually I am changing the width of a `input[type=text]` on hover. I am increasing its width using transition on hover. It works fine but when I opened the page on low resolution same amount of free sapce to expand is not there(as I used `% relative to parent[actually viewport]`). So I have to change the hover state width for small resolutions. Is it possible using mediaQueries?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can influence hover only with hover event:

```
$('#selector').hover( 
  function() { $(this).css('width','100px'); }, 
  function() { $(this).css('width','10px'); }
});
```

As an alternative you may want to use [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), to assign css classes to given elements dynamically, so basically when want your element to have hovered css class you do:

```
$('#selector').addClass('hovered');
```

and went you want your element to have have normal class you do:

```
$('#selector').removeClass('hovered');
```

This won't really replace hover event, but this way you can change css classes whenever you want.

Comment: Can you give example of add class or remove class for changing hover state?

Comment: I have edit my answer, adding or removing css classes don't depend on hover state, you can use them whenever you want.

Comment: this is adding class to selector not to its hovered state. Any css that i have mentioned in `hovered` class will also affect non-hover state, actually to all states.

Comment: Indeed it will work this way, but still, each class which you add or remove can have its own hovered state (`.hovered:hovered`), can't it?

Answer (score 1):

You could load another stylesheet that overrides the elem:hover definition (or append a style node to head) and

```
elem:hover {
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

[Here's a question to that effect.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023898/dynamically-load-css-approaches)

(Constantly binding and unbinding a hover event sounds suspicious, though. You might want to consider whether the behavior that caused you to post this question isn't itself the problem.)

Comment: Actually that will work. But I hope we can do same thing using @mediaqueries. Is i posSible?

Answer (score 0):

you could add a class using jQuery which has a hover selector applied to it in your css.

**e.g.**

```
elem {
  width:10px;
}
elem:hover {
  width:20px;
}
elem.jsApplied:hover {
  width:40px;
}
```

Comment: and also to `elem.jsApplied { width:40px; }`    
. What I want is to add class only to hover. Means I want to only change the hover width.